# How we can use node js with old version

Tags: java, node.js, angular, spring-boot, angular-cli

I already updated nodejs to v14.20.1 that work with Angular CLI but it is not complied with my project (lot of issues).

So I decide to use v8.10.0 and how we can keep that version and execute Angular CLI without the note below.

"Node.js version v8.10.0 detected.
The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of either v14.20, v16.13 or v18.10."

Thank you

Comment: Not sure you can. I don't think they'd add that warning for giggles, they probably truly require a newer version of node.

Comment: Note that even *security* support ended for Node.js v8 at the end of December 2019. Would you *really* want to use that? (And v14 is out of active support and only has 4 months and 3 weeks left of security support...)

Comment: You probably have a bunch of old packages that needs to be updated as well. Hopefully you dont have too many abandoned old packages. But if you want to run multiple versions of Node to try stuff out. I would suggest getting nvm, then you can switch between versions with commandline.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to run the command `npm install -g` on your angular project, that may could help

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurred because of node-sass was still in old version. So I decided to run the command below

npm uninstall -g node-sass && npm install -g node-sass

And Check node modules in node-sass and only hold 3 folders

ansi-styles
chalk
supports-color

After deployment, the system is running fine :)

Comment: Edit the command and folder names for better visibility